# Integer solutions to $x^y - y^x = 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

The equation $x^y - y^x = 1$ has integer solutions $(2,1)$, $(3,2)$ and $(k, 0)$ (for any $k > 0$).  Are there any others?  Based on the graph (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qyxoemixli, see below) it doesn't look like it, but is there a simple way to prove it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of Mihailescu's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture.

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to prove this case though.